# Flood of ConnectivityManager log messages on Android

Tags: android, network-programming, logcat

I have a routine checking for Android network connectivity, running every 1 second.

Every check adds a line to logcat.

Is there any way to disable this log spam?

> 02-16 23:36:26.249 32137-32137/com.xxxxxx.xxx D/ConnectivityManager:
>   getActiveNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state:
>   CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), roaming: false, failover:
>   false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false

```
public void updateNetworkStatus() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        networkType = networkInfo.getTypeName();    // "", "WIFI", "mobile"
    } else networkType = "";
}
```

***Updated full code**

```
package au.com.boxdev.testcon;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String networkType = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateNetworkStatus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void updateNetworkStatus() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            networkType = networkInfo.getTypeName();    // "", "WIFI", "mobile"
        } else networkType = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran this but did not see logs mentioned by you by running above code... r u doing anything else too !!!

Comment: Added the full test code. Make sure you allow ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE